# How to attract spiders to my house?

Tags: entomology

I've been living in my apartment for a year now, and noticed something lately. During spring and summer I have quite a lot of midges indoors, and even now there are some. But there are no spiders! So my question is a bit of the opposite of what all spider/house related articles are about: how do I get more spiders to my house?

Some info about my place: I live in a 40 year old apartment in Rotterdam, Netherlands on the second floor. It's always between 17 and 20°C, and the place is poorly isolated; plenty of cracks for visitors to crawl through. Also, I usually have a window open a bit. I have quite a lot of plants, and an aquarium, so I guess air humidity is relatively high. There is a large backyard with lots of weeds and some trees, however people use it for dumping old furniture so it is not a real garden (it's most likely the source of the midges).

Can I do something to stimulate spiders to come to my house?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spiders are naturally attracted to areas where preys are abundant, insects are primary source of spider prey. So you must create proper environment for insects in your home,  lights to attract nocturnal insects, flowers to attract butterflies and moths are attracted towards decaying vegetation(It may make your place smelly). Once insects are abundant then spiders are attracted towards these areas. Some parasitic wasps are predator to spiders like those belonging to Ichneumonidae, try to avoid these species. Also you can collect spider eggs and place it inside your home, so they will hatch out in your place.Some times you can see web full of spider nymphs, take it out and place it in your home.

Attracting spider to home can be achieved through buying some spider traps like poison free spider glue, which contains pheromones. Spiders are attracted to it and they will stick on them and eventually die, so you need to be careful and use the phenomenal effect of the spider trap to attract spiders or it will be dead and become useless.

The analysis revealed that the wasp spider pheromone is methylcitric acid trimethyl ester, a derivative of citric acid.

**Some other techniques to attract spiders**

> An unspecified Cheiracanthium species is attracted to the smell of petroleum and has caused problems by weaving webs inside the canister vent of particular models of Mazda vehicles, resulting in blockages and build-up of pressure that could potentially cause fuel leakage from the fuel tank and an increased risk of fire. Mazda issued a voluntary recall of Mazda 6 models built between 2010-2012, to fit them with software which would alert drivers if problems were developing.
>
> [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheiracanthium)

---

> A spider that preys on the malaria-carrying mosquito is attracted to the odour of people's smelly socks, say scientists.
>
> [Reference](http://news.bbc.co.uk/earth/hi/earth_news/newsid_9398000/9398408.stm)

---

> Eugenol baited traps we found seven individuals of two species of Thomisidae. In contrast, with the control traps, no Thomisidae were caught . Since Thomisidae were caught only in traps baitedwith eugenol, whereas no crab spiders were attracted to control traps, we postulate that eugenol served as an attractant for these spiders.
>
> [Reference](http://www.americanarachnology.org/joa_free/joa_v26_n1/joa_v26_p117.pdf)

Comment: We had a tractor with a clogged fuel filter once because a spider somehow got inside it, so an attraction to gasoline might be more widespread than just that species.

Comment: These seem like great tricks. I think I'll try Eugenol first, smelly socks and petroleum don't seem like such attractive options to use indoors;) Done some research on Eugenol, Apparently there's quite a lot of it in clove buds and leaves. Will see if I can get myself a small clove tree. Also just lay some cloves around and get some oil from them.

Comment: In addition, here's more details on growing a clove tree: http://gardendrum.com/2013/11/27/how-to-grow-cloves/

Answer (score 0):

in order to attract spiders in to your home

- make sure there is plenty of light to attract prey for the spiders
- leave a window open
- put some leaves in the corner
- if you find some insects or flies try to catch them then get some glue and stick them on the window seal

thanks for reading

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It isn't clear that this adds anything to the existing answer. 
 In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then edit your answer accordingly. Thanks! 